# How to store multiple 2D matrices in Python

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, 2d

I want to store 2D matrices in a another list or container.

I have 5 different 2d matrices. Each matrix has a size `36 X 36`. I want my output as below,

```
big_matrix = [ [36 X 36], [36 X 36], [36 X 36], [36 X 36], [36 X 36]]
```

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not restricted to pure python, Id recommend you to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/)!

f.e.

```
import numpy as np

2d_matrix = np.ones((36, 36), dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually dont need to specify the size of your matrix in python.
You can start by creating your matrices

```py
matrix1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
matrix2 = [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
matrix3 = [[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]
```

and append them together

```py
big_matrix = []
big_matrix.append(matrix1)
big_matrix.append(matrix2)
big_matrix.append(matrix3)
```

If you would like to have a better maintenance for your matrices I recommend looking into numpy matrices.

Dear
Yaz